# How to return value in a do block in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell recently, and it's a really cool language, but I'm confused about how I should "return" value in a function once I call a `do` block.

Specifically, consider the following function `parseMessage`,

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage string = do
    let brokenLine = words string
    let label = take 1 brokenLine
    if label == "E" then Error
    else if label == "I" then Info
    else if label == "W" then Warning
    else return Unknown
```

where `Error`, `Info`, and `Warning` are three constructors of the type `LogMessage`. I think there are two problems with the code - both of which I don't know how to fix:

1. How to compare if two strings are equal? Is what I'm doing correct?
2. How to "return" `Error`, `Info`, `Warning` in the if-else statement?

Also, I know that I can usually use "guards" like this:

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage string 
   | label == "E" = Error
   | label == "I" = Info
   | label == "W" = Warning
   | otherwise = Unknown
```

but where should I process

```
let brokenLine = words string
let label = take 1 brokenLine
```

Sorry if this is something really basic! Thanks in advanc3 :))

Comment: Read https://www.haskellforall.com/2014/10/how-to-desugar-haskell-code.html, specifically the sections dealing with `do` notation. You'll see that it's entirely unnecessary here, even if it isn't strictly "wrong". Also, `return` really has nothing to do with `do` notation (aside from the fact that `do` notation is designed for monads and `return` is a monad method), and has absolutely nothing to do with providing return values for functions in general.

Comment: (For example, `do let x = y; z` is entirely equivalent to `let x = y in do z`, which is entirely equivalent to `let x = y in z`.)

Comment: The reason you are OK here is that the entire body is a single (nested) expression preceded by a number of `let` clauses, so that neither `>>` nor `>>=` is introduced during the desugaring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`do` blocks are not for general computation. They're for doing monadic computation. In fact, my recommendation to beginners is to treat `do` as a special `IO` thing and *only* use it for `IO` computation. Once you're more comfortable with monads, you can extend that to other monadic contexts.

Similarly, the word `return` is *not* a `return` statement like it is in other languages. It's actually a terribly-named synonym for the [`pure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure) function, which wraps a value in a minimal applicative (or, in `return`'s case, monadic) context.

But you're not doing `IO` here. You're not doing anything monadic at all. You're doing an ordinary pure computation. So you don't need `do`.

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage string =
    let brokenLine = words string
        label = take 1 brokenLine in
    if label == ["E"] then Error
    else if label == ["I"] then Info
    else if label == ["W"] then Warning
    else Unknown
```

and we can get rid of those `else if`s with a pattern match.

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage string =
    let brokenLine = words string in
    case take 1 brokenLine of
      ["E"] -> Error
      ["I"] -> Info
      ["W"] -> Warning
      _ -> Unknown
```

Finally, `string` is a `String`, so `brokenLine` (after being tokenized) is a `[String]`. `take` takes a prefix, i.e. another `[String]`, so I imagine what you want is `head`, which returns the first element, *not* as a list.

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage string =
    let brokenLine = words string in
    case head brokenLine of
      "E" -> Error
      "I" -> Info
      "W" -> Warning
      _ -> Unknown
```

and if you want to be prepared to handle the case of the empty list as well, you can pattern match directly on the list

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage string =
    let brokenLine = words string in
    case brokenLine of
      ("E":_) -> Error
      ("I":_) -> Info
      ("W":_) -> Warning
      _ -> Unknown
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is super cool and elegant! Thanks for the response!

Comment: It's worth noting that none of these examples typecheck. In example 1, `label :: [String]`, but is compared to items of type `String`. In example 2, `take 1 brokenLine :: [String]`, but it's case matched against items of type `String`. In example 3, `head brokenLine :: String`, but is case matched against items of type `Char`. In example 4, `brokenLine :: [String]`, but is case matched against items of type `String`.

Comment: @luqui Thank you for trying to edit my answer, but I think you introduced some type errors (Andrew beat me to describing them). I've rolled back the edit for now.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The first two still don't typecheck, but the latter two are fixed.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo oops right, I just noticed the transformation from the 2nd to 3rd example changed some types inconsistently, but didn't look hard enough.

Comment: @luqui Thanks! I think that all looks right now. My bad as well, since the first half of the code samples had an error in the original post too :P

Answer (score 0):

Some additional notes:

- You are comparing strings correctly.  The trouble is that `take 1 brokenLine` is a *list* of strings (which only has one element).  So you need to compare it against another list, e.g. `label == ["E"]`.
- Your question about where to put the supporting definitions in your guards solution is answered perfectly by a `where` clause:

  ```
  parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
  parseMessage string 
     | label == ["E"] = Error
     | label == ["I"] = Info
     | label == ["W"] = Warning
     | otherwise = Unknown
    where
     brokenLine = words string
     label = take 1 brokenLine
  ```